# How to fill datatable only if column are not empty (OLEDB EXCEL)

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

Actually i have a program where i import excel files to mysql database

But i've got stuck on some excel files that are not imported properly, actually after selecting an excel file i load it in a DataGridView but in some excel files probably there are some **formatted empty cells** so when there are just 3 column with data are load like 300 column from which 297 are empty

So is there a way to fill DataTable by skipping empty cells / empty columns?

Here is my method where i create dataGridView (HDR is set to no deliberately)

```
 Private Sub CreateDataGrid(ByRef strFileName As String)


        TxtUpload.Text = ""
        TxtUpload.Text = strFileName.Remove(0, strFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
        TxtUpload.Tag = strFileName

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try

            'IMEX = 1 e HDR = NO prende i dati formattati ed esatti dal file EXCEL
            Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"""
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constring & "")

            con.Open()

            Dim myTableName = con.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")


            Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", myTableName)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con)
            da.Fill(dt)

            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                If dt.Rows(0)(i).ToString <> "" Then
                    col.ColumnName = dt.Rows(0)(i).ToString
                    i += 1
                Else
                    i += 1
                    Continue For
                End If

            Next
            dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows(0))

            MetroGrid1.DataSource = dt
            For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In MetroGrid1.Columns
                c.ReadOnly = True
                c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
            Next

            MetroGrid1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect
            PictureBox1.Visible = False


            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do all the excel sheets have just 3 columns of data? Is it always the first 3 columns in the speadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

try changing the query statement line to something like this:

```
Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}] WHERE column IS NOT NULL", myTableName)
```

adapt it to the format you are using in your excel files.

Your `sqlquery` variable will be responsible for what your `DataTable` will contain, so here is where you can filter your data as you desire.

Comment: the problem is that each excel file is different and i can't know what to put in 'column'

Comment: well, sadly the SQL statement needs to be explicit with the data you want to retrieve. However, you can add a function to your macro to detect these empty cells, but that is whole different alternative